# Mismatching versions-error when trying to install unlocked package

Tags: salesforcedx, package, api-version

I created a new version of my unlocked package and tried to install it into a scratch org. Unfortunately I get the error `Mismatching versions.`.

From what I know this error comes up, when one tries to install higher api-version sources into a lower api-version org.

How is the api version of unlocked packages set? Is it in the `sfdx-package.json`? I did not change anything there, it is still `"sourceApiVersion": "43.0"` as it was before. Furthermore is the scratch org is API version 44, so it should not be a problem, right?

Or am I missing something? Thanks

Comment: It seems like it is the DevHub Org's API Version which determines the package's API Version... I don't know what `sourceApiVersion` in `sfdx-package.json` is for then though...

Answer (score 1):

Usually this means your devhub has a different version of Salesforce compared to the scratch org you want to install the package on.
The version of you Salesforce org you can check on this website: https://status.salesforce.com/